# Modifying DataTable rows in loop does not persist change

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, datatable

I have the below code which is attempting to modify each row in a DataTable but after the loop over the rows where modification takes place, when I look at the rows collection the column LOCATION is empty even though the loop just populated it. Can anyone help?

```
        dtBoxes.Columns.Add("LOCATION");

        dtBoxes.DefaultView.Sort = "PALLETID";
        foreach (DataRow row in dtBoxes.DefaultView.ToTable().Rows)
        {
            var locationRow = dtLocations.Select("ID = " + row["ID"].ToString());
            if (locationRow != null)
            {
                row["LOCATION"] = locationRow.First()["LOCATION"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about `DataViews` but I would guess that the `ToTable()` is creating new instances of the rows.

Try modifying the loop to

```
foreach (DataRowView row in dtBoxes.DefaultView)
{
    //....
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but does that keep the datatable in order?

Comment: @Jon I don't see how it would change, but test it.

Answer (score 0):

dtBoxes.Columns.Add("LOCATION");

```
    dtBoxes.DefaultView.Sort = "PALLETID";
    foreach (DataRow row in dtBoxes.DefaultView.ToTable().Rows)
    {
        var locationRow = dtLocations.Select("ID = " + row["ID"].ToString());
        if (locationRow != null)
        {
            row["LOCATION"] = locationRow.First()["LOCATION"].ToString();
        }
    }


dtBoxes.UpdateChanges() // Add this line and check
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a DataTable you need to Take another DataTable and then you need to iterate through entire cells in the datatable as shown in the code.We cannot modify the rows in the same table because it will throw an exception saying "Collection was Modified".We have to take a new datatable.

Consider the following code.

```
     //To get the result with leading zero's in excel this code is written.
    DataTable dtUpdated=new DataTable();
    //This gives similar schema to the new datatable
    dtUpdated = dtReports.Clone();
        foreach (DataRow row in dtReports.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtReports.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                string oldVal = row[i].ToString();
                string newVal = "&nbsp;"+oldVal;
                row[i] = newVal;
            }
            dtUpdated.ImportRow(row); 
        }
```

Suppose in the above code a "space" was added to the text of all the cells by taking a new datatable.